# C Comparing numbers, storing in array, and print

Tags: c, arrays, printing, io, compare

What I need to do is given the input of one line of numbers such as:

```
7 5 3 4 1 2
```

I want to be able to scan and compare each number and remove the highest and lowest, and then reprint the list (in the same order that they originally were).

Example output:

```
5 3 4 2
```

Here is my code so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main( ){
    int low = 10000;
    int high = -10000;
    int current;
    char c;
    int array[6] = { };
    int i = 0;
    scanf( "%i", &low );
    high = low;
    while ( ( c = getchar( ) ) != EOF ){
        scanf( "%i", &current );
        if ( current < low ){
            array[i] = low;
            low = current;
            i++;
        }
        else if ( current > high ){
            array[i] = high;
            high = current;
            i++;
        }
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
        printf( "%i ", array[i] );
    }
}
```

I'm having a difficult time finding out where I am going wrong. My code in theory makes sense (I just started C by the way) but I cant figure out why it is not storing them into the array properly to be displayed. I get output:

```
7 5 3 0
```

Comment: You should change these lines: `int low = 10000; int high = -10000;`.  In the header `limits.h`, there are macros that have the highest and lowest values for `int`s: `int low = INT_MAX; int high = INT_MIN;`.

Comment: How does this even work, with that empty curly brackets assignment to the `array[6]`?

Comment: The code looks, sorry but, hopeless. I could write it from scratch, with explanations, if you think that would help. Perhaps you should just skip back to an easier task though...

Comment: If I am going about this the wrong way that would help me out alot ThoAppelsin, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is your problem

```
if(current < low){
  array[i] = low;
  low=current;
  i++;
}
else if(current > high){
  array[i] = high;
  high=current;
  i++;
```

}

This puts the old high or low into the position that the new high or low goes. Thus you are also reordering the array every time that you find a new max or min.

It also appears that you are reading the inputs oddly. The function scanf is the input analog of printf, providing many of the same conversion facilities in the opposite direction. The first scanf puts 7 into low, the getchar picks up the space, and then puts the 5 into low and 7 into the array so it shows up as the first element in the array. It is unable to detect that it should be the maximum.

Since you use an else if you will not get a possible high until something cannot be a possible low. Thus, your code thinks that the 4 is the maximum.

The last element of the array is 0 because the while exits after the 2 without putting it into the array. This is therefore an artifact of the compiler. Old versions of C would have shown you whatever happened to be in the memory cell unless you explicitly set the initial value.